# SSL certificate for CNAME

Tags: ssl-certificate, cname-record, iis-8

We have added CNAME for AWS Amazon S3 domain. Like below

`test.domain.com IN CNAME d5f29cy3a2ai3ip.cloudfront.net.`

We already have the SSL certificate for the domain "www.domain.com". But don't have any SSL certificate for "test.domain.com".

When I use the AWS Amazon S3 link in secure mode like https://d5f29cy3a2ai3ip.cloudfront.net its running perfectly as they have their own secured domain. We need to have similar secure SSL setup for https://test.domain.com.

We just have the SSL certificate for www.domain.com got by some other certificate provider (GeoTrust). How can I add SSL for the domain test.domain.com?

Help me to solve this.

Regards,
Karthik.

Answer (score 4):

You need a new certificate for test.domain.com -- you can't add it to an existing certificate that has already been issued. If you'll be doing much else with subdomains, you might consider getting a wildcard certificate for *.domain.com.

Comment: thanks, but can we add the new certificate for test.domain.com to any server? Hence its the CNAME i'm confused about this?

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's a CNAME or an A record -- the name just has to match what the browser is using to access the site. Whether you can add it to any server depends on the licence conditions of your certificate provider -- there's no technical problem with doing so.